# Definition of custom coordinate system with Equator rotation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

I need to define cylindrical coordinate system in ArcGIS Desktop with numeric equator rotation. Pictures below show how Equator is rotated. 
Coordinates of points 1 and 2 are known.

Is there a way to do it in ArcGIS Desktop?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The equator isn't really being rotated, it's being distorted or warped.

Comment: I would think that what you need is to make a transformation to the projection. Specifically a transformation of pole rotation on a cylindrical projection. I do not know if it can be done in arcGIS desktop. Maybe this link to the [General Oblique Transformation](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/ob_tran.html) in PROJ.4 could be useful to you.